# How do I export Physique animations without breaking them?

Tags: animation, 3dsmax, skeletal-animation, skinning, biped

I've been trying to export a simple footstep animation that I made in 3ds Max, but it either fails to export or is broken (imports into unity missing a few frames, or appears to have imported but won't play) every single time.

I've tried `.fbx` and `.3ds`, but neither works. I'd rather not use the Skin modifier, because it would require starting from scratch and learning a new system. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit the question to elaborate on "broken"?

Comment: Of course, I'll do that now.

Comment: In general, you need to bake any animations before bringing them into a game engine. If this applies to this setup i cannot say but that is my hunch.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did in the work around. Further research seems to be saying that Physique is broken for FBX, so that explains my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround, as originally by provided by Paul Ferris himself in an edit to the question, and reproduced here as community wiki:

> I found a workaround, here it is if you're curious:
>
> - Create your biped, and make sure it lines up with your mesh.
> - Animate it
> - Export the mesh without Physique (or with Physique turned off), then delete it (the mesh)
> - Export the biped
> - Recombine in Unity (or whatever your game engine of choice is)